# WPF : Custom Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, wpf-controls

I try to edit style in wpf like this :

[image]

which allow the user design, like this

[image]

but when i try to create my own style there is chrome layer not Template and I can not create my own button, I can only modify simple value like brush , ......

[image]

Comment: To be honest, it would be a better idea if you start with a tutorial, like [this one](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFControlTemplates.aspx). You won't learn much if you let Blend dump a load of code in your app. Just my two cents.

Comment: I agree with @MikeEason: this question looks more like a request for online tutoring and code-writing service. Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Milad just remove that chrome layer and include border in the template (write your own triggers for mouseover and click):

```
<Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
```

Triggers:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Chrome" Value="Blue"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: why there is chrome,  in older version of blend (v < 13 ) there is no chrome

Comment: Milad, chrome is the class they are using for style is presentationframework. it has some more properties as RenderPressed etc.

Answer (score 1):

Very detailed canonical example of WPF `Button` control styling via XAML is provided in Micrsoft MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border>
          <Rectangle Margin="2"
                     StrokeThickness="1"
                     Stroke="#60000000"
                     StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Button -->
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
          Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
  <Setter Property="MinHeight"
          Value="23" />
  <Setter Property="MinWidth"
          Value="75" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                x:Name="Border"
                CornerRadius="2"
                BorderThickness="1">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                 EndPoint="0,1">
              <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderLightColor}"
                                Offset="0.0" />
                  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}"
                                Offset="1.0" />
                </GradientStopCollection>
              </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>

          </Border.BorderBrush>
          <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                 StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                            Offset="0" />
              <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                            Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
          </Border.Background>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" />
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"
                                  To="Pressed" />
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource ControlPressedColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderDarkColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderLightColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DisabledControlDarkColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).
                      (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                         Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderDarkColor}" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsDefault"
                   Value="true">

            <Setter TargetName="Border"
                    Property="BorderBrush">
              <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                     EndPoint="0,1">
                  <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStopCollection>
                      <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushLightBrush}"
                                    Offset="0.0" />
                      <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor}"
                                    Offset="1.0" />
                    </GradientStopCollection>
                  </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                </LinearGradientBrush>

              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**RESOURCES**

```
<!--Control colors.-->
<Color x:Key="WindowColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorLight">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ContentAreaColorDark">#FF7381F9</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledControlLightColor">#FFE8EDF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledControlDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledForegroundColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="SelectedBackgroundColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="SelectedUnfocusedColor">#FFDDDDDD</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlLightColor">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMediumColor">#FF7381F9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlDarkColor">#FF211AA9</Color>

<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">#FF3843C4</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlPressedColor">#FF211AA9</Color>


<Color x:Key="GlyphColor">#FF444444</Color>
<Color x:Key="GlyphMouseOver">sc#1, 0.004391443, 0.002428215, 0.242281124</Color>

<!--Border colors-->
<Color x:Key="BorderLightColor">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="BorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="PressedBorderLightColor">#FF888888</Color>
<Color x:Key="PressedBorderDarkColor">#FF444444</Color>

<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderLightColor">#FFAAAAAA</Color>
<Color x:Key="DisabledBorderDarkColor">#FF888888</Color>

<Color x:Key="DefaultBorderBrushDarkColor">Black</Color>

<!--Control-specific resources.-->
<Color x:Key="HeaderTopColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="DatagridCurrentCellBorderColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="SliderTrackDarkColor">#FFC5CBF9</Color>

<Color x:Key="NavButtonFrameColor">#FF3843C4</Color>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MenuPopupBrush"
                     EndPoint="0.5,1"
                     StartPoint="0.5,0">
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="0" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlMediumColor}"
                Offset="0.5" />
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource ControlLightColor}"
                Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBarIndicatorAnimatedFill"
                     StartPoint="0,0"
                     EndPoint="1,0">
  <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    <GradientStopCollection>
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.4" />
      <GradientStop Color="#600000FF"
                    Offset="0.6" />
      <GradientStop Color="#000000FF"
                    Offset="1" />
    </GradientStopCollection>
  </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: You are welcome! Sure, you can apply this styling technique to other controls as well. Such advanced XAML styling was done in actual WPF apps: here is a link to web site w/plenty of WPF sample apps (free downloads): http://infosoft.biz/download.aspx . Good luck with your project. Best regards,